# Getting error while retriving the getStringExtra

Tags: android, android-intent

Here is the source ...

i am getting null values while putting values in intent ...
 here i am getting value from other activity but it gives null values when i click on continue

```
private Button continue_to_addfriends;
String name = "";
String emailId = "";
String userBirthDate = "";
String password = "";
private Intent j;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_robot_verify);

    j = getIntent();

    name = (String) j.getStringExtra("name");
    emailId = (String) j.getStringExtra("emailId");
    userBirthDate = (String) j.getStringExtra("userBirthDate");
    password = (String) j.getStringExtra("password");

    System.out.println(name+" Robot Activity");

    continue_to_addfriends=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_robot_done);

    continue_to_addfriends.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),UsernameverifyActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("name", name);
            i.putExtra("emailId", emailId);
            i.putExtra("userBirthDate", userBirthDate);
            i.putExtra("password", password);

            System.out.println(password+" Robot intent putting");
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation,R.anim.animation2);
            finish();

        }
    });
```

Here is the log file...

```
![log][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Show your code from where you have sent values with intent.

Comment: Can you show that code too?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.

```
Bundle j= getIntent().getExtras();
name = (String) j.getString("name");
emailId = (String) j.getString("emailId");
userBirthDate = (String) j.getString("userBirthDate");
password = (String) j.getString("password");
```

I hope its useful to you.